# Передача unsigned long long в функцию на ассемблере

Tags: c++, ассемблер

В функцию передаются параметры типа `unsigned long long`. Как с ними работать в коде на встроенном ассемблере в этой функции? Например, как поделить один параметр на другой и вернуть результат?

Comment: Если вы про платформу intel x86и это делимое, то разбить на два long, загрузить в пару edx:eax и поделить спокойно. Если это не делимое, то смотреть в сторону SSE

Comment: Или передать указатель, скажем в ESI и потом забрать в регистры его компоненты типа mov eax,[esi]; mov edx,[esi+4]

Comment: @Mike Да, intel x86, только можете привести код, а то это моя первая программа на встроенном ассемблере в c++ ...

Comment: вот этого боюсь не могу. давно это делал и в то время из асм-вставки можно было напрямую обращаться к переменным в C, а сейчас у каждого компилятора C какие то свои представления как это делать, т.е. с теми компиляторами что были давно я бы написал вообще типа `asm { lea esi, ulong_parm; mov eax,ds:[esi] }` ну вернее перед этим посмотрел где реально переменная и если она в сегменте стека то вместо esi использовал бы ebp например.

Comment: Кстати ... процессор то 64 битный ... у вас long long какого размера, может он влезет в 64-битные версии регистров, т.е. `rax` например.

Comment: А какой диалект асма понимает ваш компилятор? Или хотя бы какой у вас компилятор?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Математика -— мать всех наук.

```
x = lsb + 0x100000000*msb
x/y = (lsb/y) + 0x100000000*(msb/y)
```

Но как быть, если операция деления целочисленная, и при делении образуется остаток? Необходимо прибавить ещё одно слагаемое:

```
x/y = (lsb/y) + 0x100000000*(msb/y) + (0x100000000/y)*(msb % y)
```

Проверим. Пусть у нас есть число `0x7F00 = 32512`. Оно делится на `8` без остатка, давая в результате `4064`. Но `MSB (старший байт) = 127`, и оно при делении на `8` даёт частное `15` и остаток `7`.

Поделим.

```
32512/8 = (0/8) + 256*(127/8) + (256/8)*(127 % 8) =
        = 0 + 256*15 + 32*7 = 
        = 0 + 3840 + 224 = 
        = 4064
```

Comment: Интересно какое отношение данный ответ имеет к сути вопроса о передаче параметров в asm-вставку ? (деление в вопросе приведено просто как пример, к сути вопроса оно отношения не имеет)

Comment: Вы не поверите, но "ассемблера вообще" не существует в природе. Есть "ассемблер процессора X" или "ассемблер процессора Y". Единственная содержательная часть вопроса про 64-битное деление на 32-разрядном процессоре.

Comment: В комментариях к вопросу ТС мне ответил (3й комент), что платформа x86 так что какой ассемблер известно. Правда не известен компилятор, а у них по разному оформляются вставки и диалекты ассемблеров отличаются. Кстати, почему вы подумали что деление именно на 32 битном процессоре. про биты там вообще ни звука :)

Comment: Алгоритм деления больших чисел один и тот же, потому что формула деления одна и та же, вне зависимости от разрядности чисел и регистров.